# OSGi - Is it possible to override a bundle's import package version using a fragment?

Tags: osgi, equinox, apache-karaf

I have a bundle (jersey-server) that imports a package (`org.objectweb.asm`) with a resolution of optional and no version specified:

```
org.objectweb.asm;resolution:=optional
```

Currently, our application is deployed to Apache Karaf (using the Equinox framework), which exports a new version of this package (`org.objectweb.asm`), namely version 4.0.  The problem I am attempting to solve is that since the jersey-server bundle does not specify a version for the package it is wiring to 4.0.  However, the version of jersey-server I am using (1.12) is incompatible with this version.  I have a 3.1 version of the package available in the container that I need the jersey-server bundle to wire to.

I have attempted to use a fragment to suit my needs, but it does not appear to be working.  I don't fully understand how fragment import-package conflict resolution works in Equinox (or Felix) to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible.  Perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, fragments are additive only. I.e. they can add extra imports to their host bundles, but they cannot replace or remove the imports of the host.

The `jersey-server` bundle is simply broken and must be fixed.

Comment: I was afraid this was the case.  In my search I had seen various information regarding the implementation details of fragment resolution and was hoping I could solve this problem.  I guess I'll just have to create a new `jersey-server` bundle with my own manifest...

Comment: @AchimNierbeck Well it only works if you luckily deploy it with the right version of its dependencies. Which kind of defeats the purpose of OSGi... you might as well just use classpath ;-)

Comment: @NeilBartlett, well it works quite well this way, take a look at the dependencies of this fragment: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-features/xbean-fragment/pom.xml
it changes the "open" version range to a strict one, and also removed the optional flag. As for Pax-Web this was required to work with newer versions of Karaf (that already contains ASM 4 ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with pax-web, I created a "workaround" for it:

https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/tree/master/pax-web-features/xbean-fragment

it's available also through maven: 
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.ops4j.pax.web%7Cxbean-fragment%7C3.0.0.M2%7Cbundle